# How to create a service to run an application in admin mode or how can we configure an application to run in admin mode always using batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I faced this problem, my task to delete some folder and some service and to change system environment variable automatically after some days of installation. So I created a .exe file which will do all above requirements. But I faced this problem for deleting service, changing environment variable we need administrator privilege.

My .exe file contains below codes

```
sc stop LaptopAudit
sc delete LaptopAudit 
REG delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /F /V MYPROJECT
start cmd /k "@RD /S /Q %projectFolder% & exit"
```

my Service creation coding is here

```
 nssm install LaptopAuditDestruct "%FolderPath%\selfdestr.exe"
```

I need to execute this selfdestr.exe file after some days automatically also in administrator mode. Is it Possible? Please Help me. Thank You. Also tried to create task scheduler there also same problem administrator mode required.

Answer (score 0):

To run programs in admin using a batch-file you must have admin permissions on your script first, if it's the same as C++. Here's something I've been using that I found somewhere on this website. Put it at the begining of your script and tell me if it worked!

```
rem Checking permissions
if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "amd64" (
    >nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\config\system"
) else (
    >nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
)

rem If error then no admin permissions
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
    echo Catching admin permissions
    timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B
) else (
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
)
```

Comment: Actually this is not my requirement. I am executing a batch file in administrator mode. There I need to do some configuration that will help me to execute something.exe file in administrator mode for rest of time. Any time I want to  run something.exe means by default it will take administrator privilege.

Comment: Then you should try removing UAC (User Account Control) using this command `reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`, or by directly modifying the registry key that is being modified by this command, or by going to Control Panelb => System and Security => Modify User Account Control settings. Remember to change this settings afterwards as it can be a security threat. Or you can also throw your app to the Windows folder and it'll be run as administrator by default.

Comment: I put one application in C:\Windows folder and it running in normal mode. Not with administrator privilege.

Comment: This in not acceptable because we cant change client system security. Just only, we have to do some configuration with our .exe file in client system to run it with administrator privilege always. And they will provide administrator privilege one time only at the time of setup of our application. If possible please let me know. Thank You.